# Android native crash weird using APP_STL=c++_static

Tags: android, android-ndk, crash, native

```
struct CheckResultProfile {
    int          netcheck_type;    //ping dns tcp http
    int          error_code;
    std::string  ip;        //ping tcp http
    unsigned int port;  //tcp http
    uint64_t     conntime;
    uint64_t     rtt;        //tcp http rtt, dns resolve time
    std::string  rtt_str;    //ping
    std::string  url;
    unsigned int checkcount;    //ping
    double       loss_rate;        //ping
    std::string  res;            //ping result
    std::string  domain_name;    //dns host
    std::string  local_dns;        //dns

    std::vector<std::string>  ipList;   //dns
    std::vector<std::string>  ipv6List;     // dns ipv6

};

struct CheckRequestProfile {
    std::string  dns_server;
    uint32_t     timeout;

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CheckResultProfile>> checkresult_profiles;

};
```

below is one crash block：

```
LOGI("msg here can output in logcat, then crash happened");
// checkresult_profiles is defined in struct CheckRequestProfile;
_check_request.checkresult_profiles.push_back(profile); // crash with most probability
_check_request.check_status = (profile->error_code >= 0 ? kCheckContinue : kCheckFinish);

if (_check_request.timeout != UNUSE_TIMEOUT) {
    _check_request.timeout -= cost_time;
       if (_check_request.timeout <= 0) {
           break;
        }
}
```

another crash block:

```
LOGI("msg here can output in logcat, then crash happened");
struct socket_ipinfo_t ipinfo;
struct socket_ipinfo_t ipv6info;
int timeout = (_check_request.timeout == UNUSE_TIMEOUT ? DEFAULT_DNS_TIMEOUT
                                                               : _check_request.timeout);
uint64_t start_time = ::gettickcount();
int ret = apirequest::sdt::kDnsError;
bool supportV4 = isGloballyReachable(true);
if (supportV4) {
   ret = socket_gethostbyname(profile->domain_name.c_str(), &ipinfo, timeout,
                                           _check_request.dns_server.c_str(), 1);
}
```

Application.mk:

```
    # The ARMv7 is significanly faster due to the use of the hardware FPU
    APP_ABI := armeabi arm64-v8a
    APP_OPTIM := release
    APP_STL:=c++_static
    APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -std=c++11
```

part of crash stack info below:

```
crash_info: Crash reason:  SIGSEGV /SEGV_MAPERR
Crash address: 0x0
Process uptime: 2893 seconds

Thread:  0  0x0
     r0 = 0xfffffffe    r1 = 0xb071e245    r2 = 0xe4100040    r3 = 0x00000080
     r4 = 0x00000001    r5 = 0x00000010    r6 = 0x00000000    r7 = 0x00000020
     r8 = 0x0000004e    r9 = 0xb848f200   r10 = 0x00000000   r12 = 0xe559dd60
     fp = 0xb093aeb4    sp = 0xb093a7a8    lr = 0xe5579a4d    pc = 0x00000000
    Found by: given as instruction pointer in context
 1  libSdt.so + 0x9e56e
     sp = 0xb093a824    pc = 0xb996c570
    Found by: stack scanning
 2  liblog.so + 0x6535
     sp = 0xb093a848    pc = 0xe488e537
    Found by: stack scanning
 3  libSdt.so + 0x388ee
     sp = 0xb093a84c    pc = 0xb99068f0
    Found by: stack scanning
 4  boot-telephony-common.oat + 0x302471
     sp = 0xb093a85c    pc = 0x72617473
    Found by: stack scanning
 5  libSdt.so + 0x41186
     sp = 0xb093a86c    pc = 0xb990f188
    Found by: stack scanning
 6  boot-telephony-common.oat + 0x302471
     sp = 0xb093a87c    pc = 0x72617473
    Found by: stack scanning
 7  boot.oat + 0x708072
     sp = 0xb093a880    pc = 0x70752074
    Found by: stack scanning
 8  libart.so + 0x42a4be
     sp = 0xb093a8b0    pc = 0xe1bed4c0
    Found by: stack scanning
 9  libart.so + 0x283e61
     sp = 0xb093a8b8    pc = 0xe1a46e63
    Found by: stack scanning
10  boot.oat + 0x2e5be5
     sp = 0xb093a8e0    pc = 0x7032fbe7
```

as the former code show,  I can see logcat print this message "log here"， and then crash， but as I know, it has no reason crash in that code block, so I doubt if caused by using c++_static.

##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##hello##

Comment: Well, what does the stacktrace look like? Also, what makes you think that this is caused by statically linking against the STL? Does it not crash if you use `c++_shared` instead? You never mention that in your question.

Comment: @Michael I have no idea，it crash obviously on a production environment，I cannot recur it so I don't try it with c++_shared yet;

Comment: Shouldn't you see the stacktrace in the Google Play Developer Console then?

Comment: Your stacktrace is missing the lines where it shows the call stack at the time of the crash.

Comment: @Michael That is where the problem is, it lack of symbolic contents so the line info is absence. And that is why I need add log info in the code T_T